# Switch Touch Bar to showing Function Keys for Minecraft/Java only

Tags: macos

Settings only allows .app programs to be added into the list of apps to show Function Keys on the Touch Bar. I use Azul Zulu java for Minecraft, and I used to be able to use the Terminal command `defaults write com.apple.touchbar.agent PresentationModePerApp -dict-add com.azul.zulu.jdk functionKeys && sudo killall TouchBarServer NowPlayingTouchUI ControlStrip` to get it to work, but that's suddenly stopped working and I cannot figure out why and another way to get what I want.

Edit: I don't know why this has been marked as a duplicate when I literally explain that the command in the answer of the associated question does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the identifiers that work for other versions of java and realized that they end in `.java`, not `.jdk`, so I tried the following command which worked!

```
defaults write com.apple.touchbar.agent PresentationModePerApp \
-dict-add com.azul.zulu.java functionKeys && sudo killall \ 
TouchBarServer NowPlayingTouchUI ControlStrip
```